# jquery selector not working - string concatenation in selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using following code snippet to insert content into textarea:

```
function insertContent(request){

    var origin_id=request.origin_id;
    var content = request.content;
    var mode= request.mode;

    if(mode==="textarea") {
        $("#" + origin_id).val(content);
        //window.document.getElementById(origin_id).value = content;
    }
}

insertContent({
    content: payload, 
    origin_id: getParameterByName("origin_id"),
    mode:getParameterByName("mode"),
    if_id:getParameterByName("if_id")
});

getParameterByName() - get query parameter
```

target html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="temp" style="width:300px;height:400px">
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

JQuery executes shows not error.
Javascript show - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Any hints
I doubt something to with string concatenation in jquery selector?

Comment: You would never get a null error with a jQuery selector. Just a length of 0 if no matches. The error message you listed would have come from the javascript `window.document.getElementById(origin_id).value` I assume? (as it says `value`). Can you clarify the current problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use `text` instead of `val`

```
  if(mode==="textarea") {
    $("#" + origin_id).text(content);
    //window.document.getElementById(origin_id).value = content;
}
```

Comment: I doubt that will fix a "Cannot set property x of *null*" error :) I suspect the question needs tweaking a bit as the error does not match the code.

Comment: jquery was being executed inside iframe. had to window.parent.$(selector). fixed.

Comment: The value property, used by `.val()` always shows the current visible value, whereas `text()'`s return value can be wrong.